# Extracting sub data from a table

Tags: sql, select, join

I would be happy for your help.

I have a table like this :

```
[MS_CODE] [MS_SML] 
1            43
1            AA
2            51
3            24
3            21
4            11
4            43
5            AA
6            11
```

I want to write a query that will serach for the [MS_SML] which shows up in group (1 or 2 or 3) And (4 or 5 or 6) in [MS_Code].

For example:

43,AA  because 43 is in a row where ms_code is 1 and 4 and same for 'AA'. I would like to create output like this:

```
[MS_Code] [MS_SML]
1            43
4            43
1            AA
5            AA
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use `exists` and apply your criteria:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.ms_sml = t1.ms_sml and t2.ms_code in (1, 2, 3)
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.ms_sml = t1.ms_sml and t2.ms_code in (4, 5, 6)
             );
```

Comment: Thank's! but in what i need to replace the? select t.* ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it.

```
select ms_code, ms_sml
from msc
where ms_sml in
(
  select ms_sml
  from msc 
  where ms_code in (1,2,3)
  intersect
  select ms_sml
  from msc 
  where ms_code in (4,5,6)
)
order by ms_sml, ms_code
```

Note: If there is more than one ms_code for a given ms_sml in the same group, this will return all of them.
Suppose AA is mapped to 1, 3 and 5, this will return

```
1  AA
3  AA
5  AA
```

If that is an issue, We may need additional logic to deal with that: for example pick the minimum value of ms_code within the group.